# How can I send or return List<T> with socket

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, c#-4.0

ther is a server and client sockets. I want to learn a way how can I send a `List<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>` object to client to server or server to client.
i want to send server-side TaskManager Threads List to client-side. this code send line by line, I want to send complate list. How can I do it?

```
private static IEnumerable<string> TaskManager()
{
    List<string> lst = new List<string>();

    foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in
    Process.GetProcesses().OrderBy(o => o.ProcessName))
    {
        lst.Add(p.ProcessName + "_" + p.Id);
    }
    return lst.AsParallel();
}

....
....
....

while (true)
{
    Socket socket = Listener.AcceptSocket();
    try
    {
        //open stream
        Stream stream = new NetworkStream(socket);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(stream);
        sw.AutoFlush = true;
        while (true)
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(
                TaskManager(), item=>
                    sw.WriteLine(item)
                );
        }

        stream.Close();
        stream.Dispose();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Disconnected: {0}", socket.RemoteEndPoint);
    socket.Close();
    socket.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `BinaryFormatter` to serialize and deserialze a List.

```cs
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

// Server side
Stream stream = new NetworkStream(socket);
var bin = new BinaryFormatter();
bin.Serialize(stream, TaskManager());

// Client side
Stream stream = new NetworkStream(socket);
var bin = new BinaryFormatter();
var list = (List<string>)bin.Deserialize(stream);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could implement all aspects of a solution yourself, i.e. serialisation, compression, sending, receiving etc. Most things can be found by reading about [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd936243.aspx) or the [System.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145039.aspx) namespace. I can however give you a very concise solution using the [network library NetworkComms.Net](http://www.networkcomms.net) here.

For the client:

```
using System;
using NetworkCommsDotNet;

namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Create a connection
            Connection connection = TCPConnection.GetConnection(new ConnectionInfo("127.0.0.1", 10000));

            //Make a request for the threadIds and get the answer in one statement. 
            string[] taskManagerThreadIds = connection.SendReceiveObject<string[]>("ThreadIdRequest", "ThreadIds", 2000);

            Console.WriteLine("Server provided an array containing {0} ids", taskManagerThreadIds.Length);

            Console.WriteLine("Send completed. Press any key to exit client.");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            NetworkComms.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

For the server:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;

using NetworkCommsDotNet;

namespace Server
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NetworkComms.AppendGlobalIncomingPacketHandler<object>("ThreadIdRequest", (packetHeader, connection, incomingPlayer) =>
            {
                //Reply with the requested threadIds
                Console.WriteLine("Received thread ID request from {0}.", connection.ToString());
                connection.SendObject("ThreadIds", TaskManager().ToArray());
            });

            //Start listening for incoming TCP Connections
            TCPConnection.StartListening(true);

            Console.WriteLine("Server ready. Press any key to shutdown server.");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            NetworkComms.Shutdown();
        }

        private static IEnumerable<string> TaskManager()
        {
            List<string> lst = new List<string>();

            foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in
            Process.GetProcesses().OrderBy(o => o.ProcessName))
            {
                lst.Add(p.ProcessName + "_" + p.Id);
            }
            return lst.AsParallel();
        }
    }
}
```

You will obviously need to download the NetworkComms.Net DLL from the [website](http://www.networkcomms.net) so that you can add it in the 'using NetworkCommsDotNet' reference. Also see the server IP address in the client example is currently "127.0.0.1", this should work if you run both the server and client on the same machine.

Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers for this library.

Comment: it is working very well, thank you. but i want to do this with System.Net.Sockets

Comment: @ASPMaker - I'm glad the solution works. NetworkComms.Net is written using System.Net.Sockets. Also please know you can now up vote answers you find useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a reliable and robust solution, use WCF instead of implementing serialization yourself.

Also, writing to stream from parallel threads would not work correctly. Parts of lines from different threads would mix together to some intangible garbage:

```
Parallel.ForEach(
   TaskManager(), item=>
   sw.WriteLine(item)
);
```